# Multiple select options hide after each selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I copied material ui example of multiple select, it worked perfectly on my project while having their values and usestate hook, when I put my state the options menu starts to hide after each selection while previously it used to hide when the user clicks outside the select component:

video of the issue: [Video](https://imgur.com/a/YICsbeb)

my MultipleSelect component:

```
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
import { Theme, useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import * as React from "react";

import styles from "./MultipleSelect.module.sass";

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
      width: 250,
    },
  },
};



const getStyles = (name: string, items: string[], theme: Theme) => ({
  fontWeight:
    items.indexOf(name) === -1
      ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
      : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
});

interface Props {
  items: string[];
  label: string;
  names: string[];
  setItems: any;
}

export const MultipleSelect = (props:Props) => {
  const { items, label,names, setItems } = props;

  const theme = useTheme();

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof items>) => {
    const {
      target: { value },
    } = event;

    setItems(
      // On autofill we get a stringified value.
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1 }}>
        <label className={styles.fontlabel}>Annotation {label}</label>
        <Select
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
          id="demo-multiple-name"
          multiple
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="Select Annotation Status"
          sx={{
            height: 37,
            width: 271,
          }}
          value={items}
        >
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={name}
              style={getStyles(name, items, theme)}
              value={name}
            >
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I call it like this:

```
const [annotationStatus, setAnnotationStatus] = React.useState<string[]>([]);
const status = ["Pending", "In-Progress", "Resolved"];
.
.
.
.

return(
...
<MultipleSelect
  items={annotationStatus}
  label="Status"
  names={status}
  setItems={setAnnotationStatus}
/>
...
)
```